# Azure Pipeline AzurePowerShell@5 fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I'm having trouble running the `AzurePowerShell@5` task in my Azure pipeline.

I have boiled it down to this simple script:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: my-azure-sub
    inline: Write-Host "Hello World"
    azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
    pwsh: true
```

... which fails with this somewhat cryptic message:

```
Starting: AzurePowerShell
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 5.185.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\adf280e2-5ea5-4fe4-a5b0-5b25afb31371.ps1'"
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_6.4.0\Az.Accounts\2.5.3\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
WARNING: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
 Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 7c995cd6-1740-4a31-ae74-d74e61f675e1 -TenantId ***
##[error]The term 'D:\a\1\s' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: AzurePowerShell
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `ScriptType: 'InlineScript'`

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ''
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Write-Host "Hello World"'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    pwsh: true
```

```
Starting: AzurePowerShell
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 5.185.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\000bd73f-ac18-49ee-b670-f1e9fda8d6e5.ps1'"
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_6.4.0\Az.Accounts\2.5.3\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
WARNING: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
 Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 26f3dfe8-09e6-475f-b019-06857f15af9f -TenantId ***
Hello World
Finishing: AzurePowerShell
```